# PIC24 Build-In Voltage Regulator

Tags: logic-level

In the datasheet of the PIC24FJ256GB206, I have read that there is an onboard voltage regulator which will drop the core voltage to 1.8V.
My question is: Will the logic levels of output pins also drop to 1.8V or will they remain to go all the way to Vdd, in my case 3.3V?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very typical situation, when a core of a microprocessor operates at voltage that is different from the voltage of I/O pads. In a better microprocessors a separate independent voltage rails usually exist that define VIH and VIL (and output levels) for I/O pins. Some devices (most notably FPGAs) have several different banks of I/Os where different I/O levels can be defined.

In the PIC24FJ256GB206 family, the I/O levels are defined by the single VDD rail, which can be from 2.2 V to 3.6 V (3.3 V nominal). This rail also supplies the internal 1.8 V core regulator. This chip does not have a separate VDDIO rail, which means that this microprocessor has limited I/O options, and cannot directly interface with other chips that require the 1.8V interface (a very frequent signal standard in modern electronics). The least I/O voltage will be a non-standard 2.2V, but it could be tolerated for 1.8V interface.

To get the standard I/O levels (LVCMOS2.5 and LVCMOS3.3) you will need to use 2.5V or 3.3V main VDD supply. And yes, the core logic usually has internal level-translation circuitry between the core and VDD levels for I/O cells.

Answer (score 1):

Output pin levels are generally a little below Vdd, but are independent of the core voltage.

The *minimum* output levels are given in the datasheet, Table 29-8:

[image]

Note these are minimums, the typical values will be somewhere between these and Vdd.

Comment: Alright.
I had seen this table, but still wasn't quite sure.
Thanks for confirming!